# Python AppEngine And HTML

Tags: python, html, integrate

I have a simple Hello World application in Python that i'm using with AppEngine, but i want to insert this in a HTML file, like this: I have a file called test.html and on it i have this snippet:

```
<center><img src="test.png></center>
// Here comes the Python App //
```

I want to put the output of the Python application in this space, like i can do with Servlets(Java).

Regards.

Comment: have you used any python templates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should work through the getting started docs at the AppEngine site.  Specifically around templates:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates.html.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Django templates - the module comes built in with the app engine. I've used it [here](http://github.com/sudhirj/mappr/blob/master/main.py) on line 42. The template used is [here](http://github.com/sudhirj/mappr/blob/master/templates/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend using a boilerplate template
    https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate
This would give you the layout and template structure for developing useful and professional sites